# Python 2.7 + Spyder + issues with OpenGL.GL, OpenGL.GLU, OpenGL.GLUT

Tags: spyder, pyopengl, pythonxy

I am using python 2.7 , and spyder as my IDE. However, I keep getting this warning message for each of the import statements.

```
'from OpenGL.GL import *' used; unable to detect undefined names
'from OpenGL.GL import *' used; unable to detect undefined names
'from OpenGL.GL import *' used; unable to detect undefined names
```

Here are my statements:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
```

My code has no errors in it, and it will run, but the display window which should be showing an object is blank. The code was given directly from my professor as a starting point on a project, I watched it run on his laptop. Does anyone have any tricks to get this going? I've already updated OpenGL using easy_install.

Comment: I think I had already had python installed someone hidden in program files ( even though I did manually uninstall 2.7 ). I miss the old days when we would use punchcards for our programs.

Comment: Can someone close the question please.